# Excel VBA SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) returns nothing

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a script that runs a few commands on a user selected range from a filtered table. It worked fine until I tried adding a step that removes hidden cells from the range. This is an abbreviated version:

```
Sub selectVisible()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rawrng As Range
    Set rawrng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select your range", Title:="Select Range", Type:=8)
    If rawrng.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        Set rng = rawrng
    Else
        Set rng = rawrng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End If

End Sub
```

If there is only 1 row, it returns rng just fine, but anything larger than that and it just returns rng = Nothing.

I currently have a work around in the following loop that checks if the row is visible, but it slows down the program immensely since it has to run a small loop for ranges that are often 200+ rows long. I have different modules in which this code works exactly like I expect it to, so I'm not sure what's different here

Comment: Seems to work for me. Checked using `MsgBox rng.Address`

Comment: I ran your code on a filtered and unfiltered range, selecting single and multiple rows. In all cases `rawrng` returned the area I selected.  The caveat may be that in the filtered case, the entire range was returned, not just the (potentially disjointed) range that was visible.

Comment: `Set rng = rawrng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` should fail with a run-time error if there are no cells to be returned, so it seems like there's some other relevant code you're not showing us?  What is the step where `rng` is found to be `Nothing` ?

Comment: I figured it out! The sheet I was working in got protected somehow, but it was just setting rng = Nothing rather than giving me an error message about not being able to use SpecialCells on a protected sheet. Thanks everyone for looking into this!